# multi image upload fails

Tags: php, html, file, image-upload

I'm trying to allow for multiple image upload within a form. However it doesn't quite work and I can't spot the problem.

The form looks like this:

```
<form method="post" action="add-property.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="file" multiple="multiple" name="files[]" />
<input type="submit" name="submit" class="property-submit" value="Submit Property" />
</form>
```

The PHP that follows (on the same page) is:

```
//Image logic    
for ($i = 0; $i < count($_FILES['files']['name']); $i++) {
    if (($_FILES['files']['type'] == "image/jpeg") || ($_FILES['files']['type'] == "image/png") || ($_FILES['files']['type'] == "image/jpg")) {
        if ($_FILES['files']["error"] > 0) {
            echo "Return Code: ".$_FILES['files']["error"]."<br />";
        }
        else {
            $target = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/images/property-images/';
            if (file_exists($target.$currUser.$_FILES['files']['name'])) {
                echo $file["name"] . "already exists.";
            }
            else {
                move_uploaded_file($_FILES['files']["tmp_name"],
                $target.$currUser.$_FILES['files']["name"]);
                echo "Stored in: ".$target.$currUser.$_FILES['files']["name"];
            }
        }
    }
    else {
        echo 'error';
    }
}
```

$currUser is the current username of the user.

The problem is - when I try to then upload the file. Nothing happens. It echos an error but the filetype is definitely correct. No image is sent to that folder. Where could I be going wrong?

edit - requested var dump:

```
array(1) {
  ["files"]=>
  array(5) {
    ["name"]=>
    array(1) {
      [0]=>
      string(17) "Chrysanthemum.jpg"
    }
    ["type"]=>
    array(1) {
      [0]=>
      string(10) "image/jpeg"
    }
    ["tmp_name"]=>
    array(1) {
      [0]=>
      string(14) "/tmp/php1WEAjj"
    }
    ["error"]=>
    array(1) {
      [0]=>
      int(0)
    }
    ["size"]=>
    array(1) {
      [0]=>
      int(879394)
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Could you paste the result of `echo "<pre>"; var_dump($_FILES); echo "</pre>";`?

Comment: Sure thing, will add it to main in an edit

Comment: "It echos an error but the filetype is definitely correct." What error? Posting the error always helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Excluding `count($_FILES['files']['name'])`, you need to add `[$i]` to each of your `$_FILES` references, e.g., `$_FILES['files']["tmp_name"][$i]`.

Also, `$file["name"]` should be `$_FILES['files']["name"][$i]`.

Comment: Oh very good! Well spotted. Thank you for your prompt help :)

Answer (score -1):

```
for ($i = 0; $i < count($_FILES['file']['name']); $i++) {

if (($_FILES['file']['type'][$i] == "image/jpeg") || ($_FILES['file']['type'][$i] == "image/png") || ($_FILES['file']['type'][$i] == "image/jpg")) {
    if ($_FILES['file']["error"][$i] > 0) {
        echo "Return Code: ".$_FILES['file']["error"][$i]."<br />";
    }
    else {

        if (file_exists("upload/".$_FILES['file']['name'][$i])) {
            echo $_FILES['file']["name"][$i] . "already exists.<br>";
        }
        else {
            move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']["tmp_name"][$i],
                "upload/".$_FILES['file']["name"][$i]);
            echo "Stored in: ". "upload/" .$_FILES['file']["name"][$i];
        }
    }
}
else {
    echo 'error';
}
```

}